Can't Find Resource node.exe
I have a program that is currently taking a specific Javascript file and it's going to prettify it for me. The method provided by ChatGPT 4.0 is supposed to work but I am having a hard time having my code see that I do have node.exe embedded as a file. It's there, and I have the .exe in multiple locations within the project folders for verification. What Am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Flurl.Http;

namespace JSFilePrettifier
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        public static async Task DownloadFileAsync(string fileUrl, string fileName, Action<string> updateStatus)
        {
            try
            {
                var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                await fileUrl.DownloadFileAsync(Path.GetDirectoryName(tempFilePath), Path.GetFileName(tempFilePath));

                var totalBytes = new FileInfo(tempFilePath).Length;
                updateStatus($"Total file size: {totalBytes} bytes");

                using (var inputStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[8192];
                    long totalRead = 0L;
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        totalRead += bytesRead;

                        if (totalBytes != -1L)
                        {
                            double progress = (double)totalRead / totalBytes * 100;
                            updateStatus($"Downloaded {totalRead} of {totalBytes} bytes ({progress:0.00}%)");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            updateStatus($"Downloaded {totalRead} bytes");
                        }
                    }

                    updateStatus($"Final downloaded size: {totalRead} bytes");
                }

                File.Delete(tempFilePath);
                updateStatus("Download complete.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                updateStatus($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public static string PrettifyJavaScript(string jsCode)
        {
            try
            {
                string nodePath = ExtractResource("node");
                string jsBeautifierPath = ExtractResource("JSFilePrettifier.Resources.js_beautify");
                string tempInputPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                string tempOutputPath = Path.GetTempFileName();

                File.WriteAllText(tempInputPath, jsCode);

                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = nodePath,
                    Arguments = $"{jsBeautifierPath} {tempInputPath} -o {tempOutputPath}",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }

                string prettifiedJsCode = File.ReadAllText(tempOutputPath);

                File.Delete(tempInputPath);
                File.Delete(tempOutputPath);

                return prettifiedJsCode;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error during prettification: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public static string ExtractResource(string resourceName)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourcePath = $"{resourceName}";

            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath))
            {
                if (stream == null)
                    throw new Exception($"Resource '{resourcePath}' not found.");

                var tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                return tempPath;
            }
        }

        public static string GetOutputFilePath(string inputFilePath)
        {
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFilePath);
            string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFilePath);
            string outputFileName = fileNameWithoutExtension + "-Decompiled.js";
            return Path.Combine(directory, outputFileName);
        }
    }
}


I am getting an error at this line:
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception($"Error during prettification: {ex.Message}");
}

And this is the Error I am receiving:

System.Exception: 'Error during prettification: Resource 'node' not found.'

Here are the photos showing what I have in the Resources:
Showing the Resources
Node.exe is set as an embedded Resource
Can someone look at my code and see what is wrong and why I am getting this error?
I tried revising the code multiple time, including the name of the resource as well as the name of the file that it's looking for in the code.

Have you installed nodejs?

@DanielA.White yes, it is installed.

Oh it looks like it’s expecting an embedded resource

@DanielA.White yes, I would like it to be embedded because I would like to share the program to my friends who wouldn't need to install node for it
